# Show and Hide div's JavaScript works in IE but not Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I have a number of spans (20 - to be exact) they all have Id's.
I then in my style sheet I set the visibility to hidden.

I made this script to show and hide these spans once clicking on a section of the image map:

```
function showDiv(pass) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('span');    
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].id.match(pass)) {
            (pass).style.visibility = 'visible';
            divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }          
    }
}
```

It works perfectly in IE but Firefox doesn't budge, Chrome displays it alright enough with minor problems that I think I can fix.

Anyone know why Firefox doesn't accept?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and compensated for in the after life :)

Answer (score 2):

```
style.display = 'none';
style.display = 'inline';
```

**EDIT**

Here is my source

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: @Chaos: He may actually want to change the `visibility` since he may want the `hidden` spans to occupy space in the layout, just not appear.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that still works in IE but not FF.
I haven't a clue as to why.

Comment: @RockSteady: You can't refer to an element using a global variable reference in Firefox. See Josh's answer or mine for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are passing in a string, and then later using it as an element reference.  IE must be smart enough to search the DOM and find an element with an ID matching the string.

Try this...

```
if (divs[i].id.match(pass)) {
    document.getElementById(pass).style.visibility = 'visible';
    divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

**Or** it could be that the [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/match) function is expecting a RegExp.  If the above does not resolve your problem, try this...

```
if (divs[i].id.match(new RegExp(pass, 'gi'))) {
```

Comment: Yes the match was expecting a Regular Expression, the RegExp code cleaned it up nicely for IE and Chrome but still no results for FF. 

I'm beginning to think it doesn't recognize: document.getElementsByTagName('span')

Comment: FF definitely recognizes `getElementsByTagName`.  Did you try *both* things I've mentioned in this answer (together)?

Answer (score 0):

`pass` is an ID. In Firefox, element ids in the DOM aren't available as global references. You can't do *id*`.style.visibility = 'visible';` Instead your function should look something like this:

```
function showDiv(pass) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('span');    
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].id.match(pass)) {
            divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }          
    }
    document.getElementById(pass).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

You should be able to set the `visibility` of `pass` outside the loop since you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (divs[i].id.match(pass)) {
```

Is `pass` really a regular expression? Seems unusual to be using `match` here.

```
        (pass).style.visibility = 'visible';
```

This makes no sense whether pass is a string or a regex; neither have a `style` property. Putting the variable in parentheses has no effect. It doesn't work in any browser for me, including IE.

I would guess you meant:

```
function showDiv(pass) {
    var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('span');    
    for (var i= 0; i<divs.length; i++)
        divs[i].style.visibility= divs[i].id==pass? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}
```

Note also the `var i`: this is necessary to stop `i` becoming a global variable. It is a very common source of weird errors when two `for i` loops start interfering with each other.